# Alpha vantage AAPL prices do not align with other data sources

Tags: python, alpha-vantage

I'm using the following code to download and plot AAPL daily stock prices:

```py
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ts = TimeSeries(key='YOUR_API_KEY', output_format='pandas')

data, meta_data = ts.get_daily(symbol='AAPL', outputsize='full')
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

data['3. low'].plot()
plt.grid(linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
plt.title('AAPL stock price daily')
plt.savefig('sample.png')
plt.show()
```

This is the plot that I am getting:
[image]

Obviously, this price drop in 2015 doesn't look right. Also AAPL has never been that expensive. Moreover, this data contradicts with other stock prices sources, e.g. Google.

Am I misusing the API? Is this a bug?

Comment: alpha_vantage is providing you unreliable data, just export `data` to a csv and check for yourself: `data.to_csv("AAPL.csv")`

Comment: @PedroLobito You mean the python's package is unreliable?

Comment: No, their data, it doesn't matter how you get it. - https://finance.yahoo.com/chart/AAPL

Comment: They don't take into account the 2014 Seven for One Stock Split : https://www.investopedia.com/articles/active-trading/080715/if-you-would-have-invested-right-after-apples-ipo.asp

Comment: You're using the unadjusted endpoint, which doesn't take stock splits into consideration. You need to use the adjusted endpoint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Pedro Lobito noted, the data should be adjusted with stocks split times. So, after using `get_daily_adjusted` function and plotting `'5. adjusted close'` values, the result is as expected:
[image]

Code:

```py
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ts = TimeSeries(key='YOUR_API_KEY', output_format='pandas')

data, meta_data = ts.get_daily_adjusted(symbol='AAPL', outputsize='full')
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

data['5. adjusted close'].plot()

plt.grid(linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
plt.title('AAPL stock price daily')
plt.savefig('sample.png')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Alpha Vantage historical values, does not compensate for share splits.
It shows splits as sharp fall in value.